# How do compile a project that consists of both C & C++ source files in IAR embedded workbench for ARM?

Tags: c++, c, embedded, workbench, iar

I've two IAR embedded workbench projects (for Cortex-M3 ARM) which one of them is written in C & the other is written in C++.
I need to combine some files from these two projects to create a single new project & I cannot change language for non of my projects for some reasons (e.g I've used OOP in c++ project & some native c functions in the other one).
Now I'm seeking for a solution to combine these projects & compile it in IAR embedded workbench 6.
Any idea?

Comment: If your cross-compiler is some variant of GCC, you could use the same compiler for C and for C++ code, since GCC is able to distinguish them (provided they have different suffixes, ie `.cc` or `.cpp` for C++ and `.c`for C)

Comment: Enabling multi-file compilation in IAR embedded workbench compiler settings is the answer!

Comment: I not so sure that multi-file-compilation really is a good answer.

IMHO the answer can be found in "Options|C/C++ Compiler|Language 1". You can specify how the files in the project are to be compiled. You can choose between C,C++ or "Auto (extension-based)". This last item is what you want. Your .c files will be compiled a C, and you .cpp files will be compiled as C++. Next stop: extern "C".

Comment: Ah, could somebody please reopen the question?

Comment: im facing the same problem. did you manage to get a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Compile all c files. Compile all c++ files. Create the main() for your new project, which should be c++. Link all files, and that's it.